# Any way to skip deserialization of class members which are incompatible?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, resttemplate, json-deserialization

I am calling an external API through RestTemplate. There is one parameter in the response structure that is dynamic i.e. returns two types of values, it returns a Json structure in the success case (status = true) and an empty string "" in case of failure (status = false). The RestTemplate is throwing exception in failure case as the string is not able to deserialze into the class object. This is my response class:

```
public class Response {
    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    private DynamicClass data;
}
public static class DynamicClass {
    private String id;
    private String createdDate;
}
```

This call is throwing exception:

```
ResponseEntity<Response> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, httpRequest, Response.class);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.example.data.Response] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.data.Response$DynamicClass` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (''); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.data.Response$DynamicClass` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 78] (through reference chain: com.example.data.Response["data"])
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:741)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
.
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.data.Response$DynamicClass` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (''); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.data.Response$DynamicClass` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 78] (through reference chain: com.example.data.Response["data"])
```

Is there any way I can tell the parser to skip the deserialization of that member if it is not compatible as I don't need that empty string anyway? Or any other workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

- **Option 1::**

If you are using Spring, the simplest way to override the default configuration is to define an ObjectMapper bean and to mark it as @Primary:

Check :: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

    return new ObjectMapper()
      .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT,true);

}
```

- **Option 2::**
  Convert the response to string  and check for empty body and do the needful by converting the string to class object using object mapper.

  ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,httpRequest, String.class);

  ```
   if(!StringUtils.isBlank(responseEntity.getBody())) {

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   Response res= gson.fromJson(responseEntity.getBody(), Response .class);

   }
  ```

Comment: I would like to go with the Option 2 as I don't want to change the object mapper which would be used for other calls in the same class.
But I can't use the Option 2 as it is as the response body is not empty, only one particular parameter is empty:

{
      "status": false,
      "message": "No data found",
      "data": ""
}

This is the response I get. `data` - this is that dynamic field. Can I somehow put check on the `status` field, if it is false then I want to deserialize `data` as string otherwise as object.

Comment: @abhishek there is no conditional deserilaizing as such within the resttemplate. In option 2, what you can do is get the value of the status field, before deserializing like response.getBody().get("status") and use it to evaluate your condition and continue to deserialize or not.